# AttributeError: 'DecisionTreeClassifier' object has no attribute 'precision_score'

Tags: python, scikit-learn, decision-tree, attributeerror, precision-recall

i just recently started learning data science. this is what i wrote:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
 from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
 from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
 from sklearn.metrics import precision_score, recall_score
 import numpy as np

 #reading data
 df = pd.read_csv('titanic.csv')
 df['male'] = df['Sex'] == 'male'
 X = df[['Pclass', 'male', 'Age', 'Siblings/Spouses', 'Parents/Children', 'Fare']].values
 y = df['Survived'].values

 #spliting data into train/test
 kf = KFold(n_splits=4+1, shuffle=True, random_state=10)
 tree_scores = {'accuracy_scores':[],'precision_scores':[],'recall_scores':[]}
 logistic_scores = {'accuracy_scores':[],'precision_scores':[],'recall_scores':[]}

 #making the models
 for train_indexes, test_indexes in kf.split(X):
     X_train, X_test = X[train_indexes], X[test_indexes]
     y_train, y_test = y[train_indexes], y[test_indexes]

     tree = DecisionTreeClassifier()
     tree.fit(X_train, y_train)
     tree_scores['accuracy_scores'].append(tree.score(X_test,y_test))
     tree_prediction = tree.predict(X_test)
     #tree_scores['precision_scores'].append(tree.precision_score(y_test,tree_prediction))
     #tree_scores['recall_scores'].append(tree.recall_score(y_test,tree_prediction))

     logistic = LogisticRegression()
     logistic.fit(X_train,y_train)
     logistic_scores['accuracy_scores'].append(logistic.score(X_test,y_test))
     logistic_prediction = logistic.predict(X_test)
     logistic_scores['precision_scores'].append(precision_score(y_test,logistic_prediction))
     logistic_scores['recall_scores'].append(recall_score(y_test,logistic_prediction))

 print("Decision Tree")
 print("  accuracy:", np.mean(tree_scores['accuracy_scores']))
 print("  precision:", np.mean(tree_scores['precision_scores']))
 print("  recall:", np.mean(tree_scores['recall_scores']))
 print("Logistic Regression")
 print("  accuracy:", np.mean(logistic_scores['accuracy_scores']))
 print("  precision:", np.mean(logistic_scores['precision_scores']))
 print("  recall:", np.mean(logistic_scores['recall_scores']))
```

the two lines commented in for loop give error for both precision **and** recall, i dont know why. ALthough before when i was running both precision n recall they worked. and i cant seem to find any spelling mistake either.

i wonder if the different python syntaxes are messing with sklearn? because once i tried a combination like this:

```
X = df.loc['Plass':'Fare'].values
y = df.Survived.values
```

and it gave errors but when i used normal expected way it worked fine.

(note: the code may be wrongly indented, first time using stackexchange guys.)

Comment: Please post the errors you are posting about and some information about `titanic.csv` as well, since there is little one can conclude from what you have posted so far. While doing so, please indent the code properly, so that other contributors can run your program locally.

Comment: how can i add the .csv file for others to access? i already did tell the errors in the title?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DecisionTreeClassifier` doesn't have such a method indeed.

You need to change:

```
tree_scores['precision_scores'].append(tree.precision_score(y_test,tree_prediction))
tree_scores['recall_scores'].append(tree.recall_score(y_test,tree_prediction))
```

to:

```
tree_scores['precision_scores'].append(precision_score(y_test,tree_prediction))
tree_scores['recall_scores'].append(recall_score(y_test,tree_prediction))
```

and you're fine to go